# Meaning of "hab was für dich"

Tags: word-usage, phrase, meaning

I was following a chat the other day and encountered the phrase "hab was für dich".

*Hab* seems to be an in the imperative form, but I would like to learn the meaning of it.

Comment: Can you please give us a little bit more context? Also, you might want to take a look at [How do I ask good, on-topic questions for translations or about differences?](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/628/2594).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I thought first it is Imperative form "habe etwas für dich". Thought it could be "Help yourself".

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I live in Russia. My both English and German are not so good to ideally explain situation. Sorry.

Comment: It was most likely just sloppy written for "Ich habe etwas für Dich", like "Lemme" instead of "Let me" or "c'mon" instead of "come on".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It literally means:

> I have something for you

I doubt that there is a special meaning.

Comment: Ah! Absolutely right! "Ich hab...", "Ich habe...". Thanks!

Comment: And it can be used with physical: _"Hab’ was_ [ein Geschenk / a gift, eine Überraschung / a surprise] _für dich!"_ or meta-physical items: _"Hab’ was_ [Neuigkeiten / news, Informationen / information] _für dich!"._

Comment: @a-herrmann: See [Apostroph#Auslassungszeichen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostroph#Auslassungszeichen) for proper orthography.

Comment: What are you implying? According to http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph Regel 13 Punkt 2 it's perfectly fine to leave out the apostrophe, but you are allowed to put one.

Answer (score 3):

The "was" is colloquial (umgangssprachlich) for "etwas".

So the sentence is, in full, "Ich habe etwas für dich.", which means "I have something for you", as @5pike stated in their reply.